# Find the most repeated value of a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following  dictionary:

```
s_final = {
    a:[noun,adj,noun,noun,noun],
    b:[verb,verb,verb,noun]
}
```

I would like to retrieve the most repeated value of the keys such that my final output will be as follows:

```
s_final={a:[noun], b:[verb]}
```

Comment: So what did you try up to now?

Comment: Take care of your code. It's broken.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Counter](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s_final={'a':['noun','adj','noun','noun','noun'],'b':['verb','verb','verb','noun']}
>>> {i:[Counter(j).most_common(1)[0][0]] for i,j in s_final.items()}
{'a': ['noun'], 'b': ['verb']}
```